# How to programatically create a svg with different colors in python/django?

Tags: python, django, svg, tailwind-css

In telegram, when you have yet to upload your picture, they will programatically generate a logo based on your initials like the following

[image]

I want something similar but as SVG and ICO for a Django web app.

I only need 26 letters from A to Z. And I need to be able to change the fill color based on [taiwindcss colors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors)

The letters itself would be white or black.

Is there a programatical way to generate these svg and ico to be used in a Django webapp? I could not find any library that does this.

I only need it as a square basically

Comment: you can check out this package to create svg with text https://github.com/cduck/drawSvg